# Office Encryption Provider interface implementation

Tags: c#, encryption, ms-office, office-interop

I am new to C# and Office Addins in general, and cannot find any information on the Office.EncryptionProvider interface, which I am attempting to implement in order to create a custom method of document encryption and authentication. As I am working on implementing this interface I realized I have NO IDEA how to make office utilize my addin as an encryption provider. So my questions are as follows:

1. Can anyone point me to any GOOD documentation regarding the implementation of this interface (the msdn docs are pitiful in this respect) [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870296)?
2. Does anyone know how, once built, to establish within office (2010 preferably) my add-in as an encryption provider so i can detect/authenticate/encrypt/decrypt documents?
3. Is this even possible from an Office C# add-in perspective? and if I am going down the wrong path, what is the correct one (the goal is to create a seemless office experience)?

Update: I found a document that was helpful and I rebuilt the program to be a COM add-in which i found out is required, but I still cannot register it as the crypto provider, apparently I have to set the registry key @
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Security\OpenXMLEncryption`
but as of yet have I been able to trigger the calls to my addin for encryption. I'm hoping someone in the know can help me out ....

Comment: Could you share that doc and some more insights on your progress?

Comment: Did you found the solution??